# Order by month giving reverse order in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order a mysql query according to the month name  but it is ordering in reverse order .I have tried both the ASC and DESC order but not working!This is what i'm getting :

```
order_amount    month_number
370.245          Dec
0.01             Aug
0.02             July
0.01             May
2                Apr
3                Mar
4                Feb
5                Jan
```

This is the query:

```
select sum(amnt) as order_amount,month_number  from orders where paid =1 GROUP BY month_number   ORDER BY MONTH(month_number) ASC
```

This is a sample  table 'order' on which i'm running query

```
order_amount    month_number    paid

370.245           Jan             1

0.01              Aug             1
0.02              July            1
0.01              Apr             1
2                 May             0
3                 Mar             1
4                 Feb             0
5                 Nov             0
```

Comment: what kind of data is contained in the field `month_number` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`month_number()` is a lousy name for a string name for the month.  That said, your attempts will not work, because `month()` takes a date, not a string representation.  The best way is probably just to use `case`:

```
order by (case when month_number = 'Jan' then 1
               when month_number = 'Feb' then 2
               . . .
               when month_number = 'Dec' then 12
          end)
```

I would strongly suggest you include a date or actual month number in the table.  And, rename `month_number` to something like `month_name`.

Comment: Thanks it works.Can you tell me how i can convert the actual month number into month name?For example 1 into january 2 into feb ...... and how to order them without writing the case situation ?

Comment: @query . . . Essentially you need to convert them to a date and then order by the date.  This is simpler if you have a real date in the table to describe the month.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample, you've got **'Dec', 'Aug'** and so on in your `month_number` field.

How is `month(month_number)` supposed to work if you don't pass a valid **date** type? if you pass some random text you'll just get `NULL` and can't order by `NULL`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a774d/3/0

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
+-------+
| month |
+-------+
| Apr   |
| Aug   |
| Dec   |
| Feb   |
| Jan   |
| Jul   |
| Jun   |
| Mar   |
| May   |
| Nov   |
| Oct   |
| Sep   |
+-------+

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2014-',month,'-01'),'%Y-%b-%d');
+-------+
| month |
+-------+
| Jan   |
| Feb   |
| Mar   |
| Apr   |
| May   |
| Jun   |
| Jul   |
| Aug   |
| Sep   |
| Oct   |
| Nov   |
| Dec   |
+-------+
```

... or something like that